# GET method and PHP

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, get

I have two questions.

In my webpage (developed by me), I use the GET method to return for example the id of one record that I have in a mySQL database.

For example, one url can be this:

```
http://www.example.com/example.php?id=1
```

But in MediaWiki software, they can use this GET method, or one strange method that I don't know, that works like this:

```
http://www.example.com/example.php/1
```

How can I do that my PHP script knows that what the id is 1?

And now I have another question. In MediaWiki software, you can do that the index.php file converts to a *virtual wiki* directory.

Now the final question is: How can I do that in my webpage, the url for this request to my mySQL database (with a PHP script) is:

```
http://www.example.com/example/1
```

Thanks.

*P.D: Sorry about my bad English. I'm still learning, because I'm from Spain and in Spain the Enslish is not an official language.*

Comment: You are looking for url rewriting. There are plenty of questions and examples here on SO about that.

Comment: you need to read more about "mod_rewrite".

Comment: @Aziz: Not necessarily. He could be running IIS for all you know! I see no mention of Apache here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that with rewrites (e.g. via .htaccess)

Have a look at this page: http://www.workingwith.me.uk/articles/scripting/mod_rewrite

Comment: By the way: Make sure you do not use the GET parameters without sanitizing them first. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection and http://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 2):

Apart from using mod_rewrite, if you're using Apache+PHP, you can use the $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] var to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: No, you would still need to rewrite the url to avoid a 404 page not found error.

Comment: That's true, but I was looking at the OP's `final question`.

Answer (score 2):

Use mod_rewrite for the URL - and write a php backend which will parse the url. (fetch the get values)

This link should get you started, http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/